# Need to change Checkbox to Radio -React js

Tags: reactjs

Hi I have created checkbox using reactjs but again they asked to change checkbox to radio in the below code. I changed to type to radio but it is not working properly. Two functions(isChecked and onChange) are confusing me. I try to modified those but not working properly. Please help with this and let me know if anything required from any information.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { Form } from 'react-bootstrap'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import shoppingCartActions from '../actions/shoppingCartActions'
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next'
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom'

const DisplayProduct = (props) => {
  // Each product available to the customer in the webshopReducer[brikksId] (categories: NET, WIFI, TV, DECODER) is passed as a prop into DisplayProduct component
  const { product, id } = props
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const { t } = useTranslation()
  const { brikksid, addressid } = useParams()

  const getId = () => {
    if (brikksid) {
      return brikksid
    }
    if (addressid) {
      return addressid
    }
  }
  const shoppingCart = useSelector((state) => state.shoppingCartReducer.cart[getId()])
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(shoppingCart?.includes(product))

  // If product is in shoppingCartReducer -> checkbox checked; otherwise -> checkbox -> not checked
  useEffect(() => {
    setChecked(shoppingCart?.includes(product))
  })

  // If product has no charges (cost) -> return product name
  // Elseif product has one or more charges (costs) -> return product name + monthly cost (if exists) + establishment fee (if exists)
  const generateLabel = () => {
    if (!product.charges) {
      return product.name
    }
    const strings = product.charges.map(charge => {
      return charge.recurring ? ` ${charge.amount},- ${t('perMonth')}` : ` ${charge.amount},- ${t('coverage.establishmentFee')}`
    })
    return product.name + strings.join()
  }

  const onChange = (element) => {
    if (checked) {
      dispatch(shoppingCartActions.removeProduct(product, id))
      setChecked(false)
    } else {
      dispatch(shoppingCartActions.addProduct(product, id))
      setChecked(true)
    }
  }

  // If product is in shoppingCartReducer[brikksId] -> return "checked", otherwise -> return undefined
  const ischecked = () => {
    const checked = shoppingCart?.includes(product)
    return checked
  }

  return (
    <Form.Check
      type="checkbox"
      checked={ischecked()}
      label={generateLabel()}
      name="netradio"
      onChange={onChange}
    />
  )
}

DisplayProduct.propTypes = {
  product: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  id: PropTypes.string.isRequired
}

export default DisplayProduct
```

Comment: i dont see any radios on your code.  Can you post the actual code.  Also you could place a breakpoint in the onChange to see what is being passed in or a console.log

Comment: I posted actual code. we need to change to radio like this <Form.Check
      type="radio"
      checked={ischecked()}
      label={generateLabel()}
      name="netradio"
      onChange={onChange}
    />
  )
}

Comment: getting null  onchange in console. Like this I put console.log('onchange' + onchange)

Comment: please help with this

Comment: I guess you need at least two radio controls to simulate a checkbox: one for the "checked" state and one for the "unchecked" state. Then in your code you need to watch the selected value instead of the "checked" status. Looks like a large refactoring of your actual code.

Comment: Ok. Can you please help little on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As radio buttons let you select one value out of a set of alternative options you probably need two radio buttons to simulate your current checkbox behaviour: let's say Option 1 = `checked` and Option 2 = `unchecked`.

Honestly I find the logic in your current code a bit tricky and I can't entirely follow it, so this is just a very basic example:

```
const DisplayProduct = (props) => {
        
    ...
        
    const onChange = (e) => {
        const checked = e.target.value;
        if (checked) {
          // Do something when Option 1 is selected.
          // This should represent the "checked" state of your current checkbox
        } else {
          // Do something when Option 2 is selected.
          // This should represent the "unchecked" state of your current checkbox
        }
     };
        
     return (
        <div>
          <Form.Check
            type="radio"
            label="Option 1"
            name="netradio"
            value={true}
            onChange={onChange}
          />
          <Form.Check
            type="radio"
            label="Option 2"
            name="netradio"
            value={false}
            onChange={onChange}
          />
        </div>
     );
  }
```

You need to rethink a bit your current `generateLabel()` function as you obviously need two labels now. Maybe your `isChecked()` function as well, although it seems to me it just replicates the `checked` state so I don't really understand why you need that.